# How to use freetype library with php

Tags: php, heroku, gd, freetype

I am new to php and this is my first ever php app.

My app includes the functionality to create image on runtime while adding text into it and thus for it is utilizing the function `imagefttext()`.

My whole app was working fine on my previous server (godaddy) but recently ive transferred my app to heroku repository and now I am getting this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagefttext() …`

For googling I found out that this function requires GD & freetype libraries, I do have GD support here but freetype support is missing.

- Does Heroku doesn't support freetype lib?
- Is it possible somehow that I can use freetype library over my new
  server heroku?
- If yes then how? Do I need to include few references in my code?
- If that’s not possible, is there a way I can work around with adding
  text to images without freetype?

Comment: yes, a cloud platform as a service.

Comment: You need privilege for install freetype for server or enable it, Ask for hosting support to do it for you

Comment: thats kind of support from their is probably not possible? any alternatives?

Comment: @Maven The Freetype libary can only be installed at the server level. They must do it for you, or you will not be able to use it.

Comment: hmm, so thn is there a way I can work around with adding text to images without using freetype?
p.s.: `imagepstext` also not supported.

Comment: I have the exactly problem, if you found any solution please comment here. Thank a lot